# How to further specify an exception when there are two different errors under the same exception class

Tags: python, exception

I have two different errors under the same exception class that I want to handle differently.

1.

> Exception: ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42S22', "[42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'newCol'. (207) (SQLExecDirectW); [42S22] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Statement(s) could not be prepared. (8180)")

2. 

> Exception: ProgrammingError: (pyodbc.ProgrammingError) ('42000', "[42000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server][SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near ','. (102) (SQLExecDirectW)")

How do I further specify these errors in my try-except block so I can handle them differently?

```py
try:
    #code
except ProgrammingError:
    #code
```

Comment: You can capture the exception instance with `except ProgrammingError as exc:`. Beyond that, it depends on what interface `ProgrammingError` provides to access the information seen in the string representation.

Comment: @chepner ah okay, so capture the instance with ```as exc``` then do ```if exc == 'some string'``` and then I'd be able to handle it, basically?

Comment: Well, `str(exc)`, and you might need to use regular expressions to pick out the substring you want. Check if the exception provides any convenient attributes, e.g. can you do something like `if exc.sqlstate == "42S22": print("Invalid column")`? (I'm just guessing at the association of the codes with the specific error type. `ProgrammingError` is just far to vague to be using directly; it would be nice if there were more specific subclasses available.)

Comment: @chepner Yeah specifying attributes like that would be great, if I can do that. Is there something I could do to check for attributes? Or maybe I could specify an index in that list it's returning, hmm..

Comment: I didn't seen anything documented at https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Exceptions; I usually just capture an exception and check it with `dir` to see what there is to see.

Comment: @chepner Ended up doing something like ```if 'HY000' in str(e):
#code
                elif '42S22' in str(e): 
#code``` seems to work well (for some reason when I printed out the string for one of the errors, the error code ended up being different, hence the 'HY000'). If you have any more tips or insight as to what I could do better here I'm all ears. If not, I just want to say thank you for your help!

Comment: Nevermind about the error code being different, apparently there were two different codes that needed to be handled the same. It's now ```if 'HY000' or '42000' in str(e):```

Comment: `if any(x in str(e) for x in ['HY000', '42000']):`

Comment: @chepner Thank you, what are the advantages to writing it that way?

Comment: It has the advantage of being correct. `'HY000' or ...` is always true, because `'HY000'` is a non-empty string. `x or y in z` is not the same as `x in z or y in z`. `any(w in z for w in [x, y])` is probably overkill for only 2 items, but scales much better as the list of things to check grows.

Comment: @chepner I appreciate the heads up, I'll be switching it. Although, why is it so hard for me to wrap my head around why that wouldn't work? Would ```if 'HY000' in str(e) or '42000' in str(e)``` work?

Comment: Did some thinking, this makes sense now. python says this part is true ```if 'HY000'``` and doesn't end up comparing it to e. Thank you